# Total number of outcomes for flipping 2 coins 4 times?

Tags: combinatorics

I just wanted to make sure I understand this correctly.

Total number of outcomes for $2$ coins on $1$ flip is $2^2 = 4$.
Therefore, would flipping the $2$ coins $4$ times have $4^4 = 256$ possible outcomes?

The equation for the exponent. The base represents the total outcomes and the exponent is the total number of flips or number of coins?

Comment: Yes, there are $4^4$ possible outcomes when you flip two coins four times.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.

Comment: The total outcomes are (HH HT TH TT). You have four more of these since you flip two coins four times.$4^4$ = $256$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score -1):

let's mark $ L_i - $ the number of possibility's for one turn (flipping)
we see that for any $i \neq j$ the event $L_i \ and \ L_j$ are independence and there for the total outcome for n turn is $\Pi_{i=1}^{n} L_i $ and because $L_i = 4 $ for every i:

(h - h , h - t , t -h , t - t)
then the total outcomes number is $4^n$

Comment: I doubt somebody who's only now coming to grips with the fundamentals of combinatorics will understand this.

Comment: its simple, i don't understand were's the problem understanding.

Comment: your vote is unjustified